# How to install prerender.io on an exiting angularjs application hosted on IIS server

Tags: angularjs, iis, prerender

I have tried almost everything I found, I understand most of the examples show to set it up with a new app created with expressjs, but I haven't found anything specific for IIS.

We do have a token.

```
<!-- prerender token -->
                     <httpProtocol>
                        <customHeaders>
                            <add name="X-Prerender-Token" value="mytoken" />
                        </customHeaders>
                    </httpProtocol>
            <!-- end prerender token -->

                <!-- prerender.IO rule -->
                        <rule name="Seo rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                          <serverVariables>
                            <set name="HTTP_X_PRERENDER_TOKEN" value="mytoken" />
                          </serverVariables>
                         <conditions>
                            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                        </conditions>
                          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                        </rule>         
                    <!-- end prerender.OI rule -->
```

I added this code line in app.js

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')
```

also the meta tag

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

I can see it prerendered with the local server

http://localhost:3000/https://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/blog/This-is-great

It's my understanding that if everything is correctly configured I should see the same result if I search for https://example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/blog/This-is-great directly in the google search.

I appreciate any help you can provide me on this issue.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed be able to search in google for that string but you should be able to put it into your URL and it will work.  Also Todd at Prerender is very responsive if you Email him.  I also wouldn't be surprised if he shows up in this thread.

Comment: Yeah we're already working on this over email :) but we haven't been able to figure it out yet. Everything looks to be correct in that config so it has to be some setting in IIS.

Comment: We are running prerender.io on our IIS server. Besides the configuration I shared before, we also needed to enable ARR module in IIS  as well as add sever variable HTTP_X_PRERENDER_TOKEN under url rewrite module. Thanks  @Prerender.io  for your support. Hope this help someone else.

Comment: I am looking to setup prerender.io on our IIS server. Can you please help me to get the details of the ARR module and  sever variable HTTP_X_PRERENDER_TOKEN setup